# Are Schnute and Schnauze both cognate to snout?

Tags: etymology

I'm curious as to whether "Schnute" and "Schnauze", both meaning some variation of "mouth" or "snout" are both cognate to "snout". If so, it would appear that they have been affected differently by sound shift, and I'd be interested in how this would have come about historically. I do not have access to proper etymological literature unfortunately.

Comment: Just to confirm your suspicion that a German word is related to an English word, you can also look up the English word on Eymonline and hope that the German word is mentioned. https://www.etymonline.com/word/snout#etymonline_v_23792

Comment: While it should be well known that these are typically compared to *nose* for an s-mobile root in Proto-Indo-European \*Hnéh₂s ~ (cp. नस् (nás, nā́s, “nose”)), wiktionary calls it uncertain instead, possibly of substrate origin. It is notable that an Anatolian nose-word is *not known* to Kloekhorst. AGrk only has ῥῑ́ς (rhī́s, eg. *rhenitis* "Schnupfen"). Some (e.g. A. Liberman) speak of a phonesthem *sn-* (*snot, snob, sniff*, etc. as if onomatopeia). Now very spontaniously, since German *sch-* can reflect \*(s)k- (and \*'k > Satem *s*) I want to compare *Knute* as it pertains to mouth pieces!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are cognate. The (openly accessible) [Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen: *Schnauze*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Schnauze) sais:

> Die Formen [die mittelniederdeutschen Wurzeln von *Schnauze* und *Schnute*] gehören wie gleichbed. nl. *snuit*, mengl. *snūte*, engl. *snout*, norw. *snute* zu der lautmalenden, etw. Vorragendes bezeichnenden Wortgruppe mit anlautendem germ. *sn-*

> These forms [the middle lower german roots of *Schnauze* and *Schnute*] belong together with netherlandic *snuit*, middle english *snūte*, englis *snout*, norwegian *snute* to the group of words with beginning germanic *sn-*, who are onomatopoetic and denote something that stands out.

Answer (score 1):

While Jonathan's etymological statements are fully valid, I'd like to add some notes about their usage changes during the centuries. The word *Schnute* was never a widely used word for an animal's mouth, while the word *Schnauze* was and is. *Schnute* was originally commonly introduced as an equivalent of *Schnauze* for humans in a pejorative context. Nowadays, *Schnute* isn't that negatively connoted anymore in general as it was in the past.

Also worth to mention: The german "Schnauze!" for the english "Shut up!" is very common, but not "Schnute!". This emphasizes further on the change of its original negative connotation.